# Laravel - Group By on some specific values only

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get results from some specific values only. For example, if I have a table like this

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | B |

I want results like this.

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | B |

Which is the `group by` only on rows which have values `A`. Is this possible in a single query?

Comment: `SELECT id,name, IF(name = 'A', name, CONCAT(name,id)) as tmp_name FROM tbl_tmp group by tmp_name` This require to disable `sql_mode=full_group_by`

Comment: could you share what you tried so far. you can where condition to skip `2 A` record and then group it by name.

Comment: @Rafee I have used where condition but it doesn't seem to be possible with that

Comment: show your query.